# Riemann Hypothesis Research

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, prime-numbers, contour-integration, riemann-hypothesis

I don't know if this is the correct place for this. If not feel free to remove!

I am a recent graduate of a BSc in Applied and Computational Maths and am now not working in a maths field. I miss working on maths and would like to keep up some learning in my spare time. I would like to complete some research in the Riemann Hypothesis (I fully accept there is no chance of me solving it but it is the Millennium Problem that interests me the most and I hope it will keep my maths brain sharp in case I ever return to the field!)

During my degree, I completed multiple modules in Complex Analysis and Number Theory so I have a reasonable background in the field (I am comfortable with contour integration; complex functions etc.). Are there any textbooks anyone would recommend that are of a beginner/intermediate level that would allow me to fully understand the depth of the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: This should be allowed to ask, as there is a *book-recommendation* tag, which says use *reference-request* as well - you might want to add these.

Comment: I’m not sure what your precise level is, but the second part of Tenenbaum’s *Introduction to analytic and probabilistic number theory* could be enlightening.

Comment: "To complete some research in the Riemann Hypothesis" is not a well-defined topic. For understanding the statement, some elementary complex analysis is enough. For attempting a proof, a whole area of modern number theory is necessary (I fear).